# Cannot resolve hostnames on Android

Tags: java, android

I'm making an app that's supposed to grab data from a server and display it. When I prompt the user to login, the program will crash if they input a hostname (e.g. stackoverflow.com) whereas it will work just fine if they input the IP (and will be able to grab data from the site), for example 198.252.206.16 (Stack Overflow's IP address).

Here's some code from the app where it breaks:

```
private String buildURL(Param... params)
{
    String server = SessionInfo.getInstance().getServer();
    try{
        server = InetAddress.getByName(server).getHostAddress();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e1){
        Log.d("UNKNOWN HOST EXCEPTION", e1.toString());
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    String sessionId = SessionInfo.getInstance().getSessionId();
    String url = "http://" + server + "/" + SITE_ADDRESS + "/api/login";
    return url;
}
```

EDIT:

My AndroidManifest.xml does contain

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

so that's not the issue.

LogCat:

```
07-23 17:48:37.799: W/System.err(1447): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "SERVER": No address associated with hostname
07-23 17:48:37.799: W/System.err(1447):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
07-23 17:48:37.829: W/System.err(1447):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
07-23 17:48:37.839: W/System.err(1447):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
07-23 17:48:37.839: W/System.err(1447):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
07-23 17:48:37.849: W/System.err(1447):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
07-23 17:48:37.878: W/System.err(1447):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
07-23 17:48:37.878: W/System.err(1447):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
07-23 17:48:37.899: W/System.err(1447):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
07-23 17:48:37.899: W/System.err(1447):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
07-23 17:48:37.919: W/System.err(1447):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
07-23 17:48:37.919: W/System.err(1447):     at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.execute(AndroidHttpClient.java:252)
07-23 17:48:37.939: W/System.err(1447):     at com.app.android.rest.APIBase.post(APIBase.java:185)
07-23 17:48:37.958: W/System.err(1447):     at com.app.android.rest.LoginAPI.doInBackground(LoginAPI.java:44)
07-23 17:48:37.978: W/System.err(1447):     at com.app.android.rest.LoginAPI.doInBackground(LoginAPI.java:1)
07-23 17:48:37.978: W/System.err(1447):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-23 17:48:37.998: W/System.err(1447):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-23 17:48:38.008: W/System.err(1447):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-23 17:48:38.028: W/System.err(1447):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-23 17:48:38.028: W/System.err(1447):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-23 17:48:38.048: W/System.err(1447):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-23 17:48:38.048: W/System.err(1447): Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
07-23 17:48:38.088: W/System.err(1447):     at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
07-23 17:48:38.088: W/System.err(1447):     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:59)
07-23 17:48:38.099: W/System.err(1447):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
07-23 17:48:38.099: W/System.err(1447):     ... 19 more
07-23 17:48:38.128: D/AndroidRuntime(1447): Shutting down VM
07-23 17:48:38.128: W/dalvikvm(1447): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
```

And my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" 
                  android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/app_thumbnail"
        android:label="app Mobile"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >

        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.app.android.LoginScreenActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar"
            android:label="Mobile App" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.app.android.MonitorSettingsActivity"
            android:label="" />

        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.app.android.MainScreenActivity"
            android:label="" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.app.android.MAINSCREENACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you using the emulator or a real device?

Comment: I'm using an emulator. Also, to note, I can access the website using the emulator's browser.

Comment: define "crashing" ? It's throwing the `UnknownHostException`? Are you sure those permissions are in the right place in the manifest file?

Comment: Logcat....we need to see logcat.

Comment: Updated with logcat and manifest. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't believe that since Jul 23 '13 no one else has had this problem (or a solution to it). I used to be able to resolve/ping my Wifi connected PC's (and actually stream .mkv 's from shared folders using the excellent "File Manager HD"). Now I can't, but i dont think I 've changed anything. I can still access if I use the PC's IP, but can't resolve its name... Weird !

Comment: Well, in my case, it turned out to be a bit weird. The hostname entered was "http://server/", which crashed it. This domain was accessible by browser. However, using "server.companyname.com", the 'full' version of the URL, resolved the issue.

Comment: @aneeshashutosh You should put this as an answer. I was having the same problem, but using the FQDN (the "full version" of the URL) solved the issue for me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself (reposting the comment here for posterity):

Well, in my case, it turned out to be a bit weird. The hostname entered was `server/`, which crashed it. This domain was accessible by browser. However, using `server.companyname.com`, the 'full' version of the URL, resolved the issue.